# How to echo an 0x96 character in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, unicode, command, codepages, windows-1252

I've got a [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) project with a 0x96 character in its title, e.g. "Project – X" which I need to reference in a batch file. The problem is that this particular dash is represented by 0x96 (and not 0x20) which is a control character in Unicode (û in ASCII?), so the following (in an ANSI encoded .cmd file) fails as "Project û X".

```
echo "Project – X"
```

But when pasted straight to the command line (I think) it cheats and translates the 0x96 to a 0x20 (which is no good as my file names don't match). I tried this with a hex editor and it looks like there's some cheating going on.

The .cmd file won't work if it's encoded as anything but ANSI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
chcp 1252
set "name=Projekt û X.txt"
chcp 850
type "!name!"
```

The important thing is the **chcp 1252**, the chcp 850 is only to switch back to my default code page, but it is not neccessary.

Answer (score 4):

By default, cmd.exe uses the old "OEM" codepages whereas pre-Unicode Windows applications use the "ANSI" codepages ([Code Pages Supported by Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964653.aspx)).

You will ([as jeb alludes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595451/how-to-echo-an-0x96-character-in-a-batch-file/4595517#4595517)) either have to save your text file in the OEM encoding (assuming that character is even in it) or [switch your console](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html#charsets_1252) to the ANSI encoding.

Comment: thanks for the info on changing code pages, am reading up on it now